# What happened to Kaneki in episode 12 of Tokyo Ghoul:re?

Tags: tokyo-ghoul

In episode 12 of *Tokyo Ghoul:re*,

> Kaneki gets his memory back.

However, I didn't understand the dialogue "well sleep, Haise" before that, and the following event regarding Kaneki's memory.

What actually happened?

Answer (score 0):

The metaphor is that Kaneki is putting Haise to sleep, as now Kaneki has taken over by regaining his memories. Haise will never come back, as he has become a part of Kaneki. The 'cliffhanger' now is how will Kaneki act around his friends that Haise made, and what will he do next.